# Remove appcompat_v7 project without affecting its functionality

Tags: android, eclipse

While create an Android project in eclipse, it created 2 projects.

1. appcompat_v7
2. MasterCopy <- This is the name of my project

I understand that appcompat_v7 is a library project that android automatically created for me.

Once the above projects are created I got an error message 'The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library'.  To address this I just build the appcompat_v7 project and that clears the error.

Basically I don't want appcompat_v7 as a separate project.  This is how looks like.

[image: appcompat_v7 project folder structure]
[image: MasterCopy project folder structure]

If I delete the appcompat_v7 project I got the 'Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar' in styles.xml file.

Is there a way I add appcompat as external library or JAR file into the MasterCopy project and keep one project as whole without loosing the functionality?

I am not sure whether I am making any sense here... But this is how I asked to create the project.

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation

The issue you're going to have is that resources, such as styles like `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`, cannot be packaged simply in a jar file. As Google's documentation explains:

> Some Support Libraries contain resources beyond compiled code classes,
>   such as images or XML files. For example, the v7 appcompat and v7
>   gridlayout libraries include resources.

Google has specific documentation for how to include libraries that contain resources, which it appears you've followed:
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

The reason why it's a good idea to keep this in a separate project, is that it allows you to easily upgrade, build, and otherwise manage that project separate from your own as the compatibility library changes.

#### (Unrecommended) Solution

That said, if you *really* want to have a single project, you could manually copy everything from the sample project for the app compat library (located in `<sdk>/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/`) **into** your project. Notably, you'll need to copy everything from the `res/` folder and merge it with your own resources, or rename google's XML files such as `res/values/strings.xml` to `strings-appcompat.xml`, and of course the appcompat jar file itself.

Again though, you'll have to go through this process every single time you want to update the version of the compatibility library that you use.

#### (Good) Alternative Solution

Google has specifically created the `AAR` format, which bundles resources with a jar file. If you transition to a Gradle build system (easy if you're using Android Studio), then all you have to do is refer to this app-compat-v7 `aar` artifact (also explained at the link above), and you can maintain a single project.